# leanmodel.js is not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi i am new to so so please ignore my errors on posting question.

I am using leanmodel.js for opening popup. it is working fine on my page but when i change the content of page using ajax call then leanmodel.js is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({ top : 100, closeButton: ".modal_close" });       
});
</script>
```

Edit :

I have put this code in a function and have called function after ajax success but unfortunately not working.

```
function myFunc(){
$('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({ top : 100, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a delegate method such as

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[rel*=leanModal]', function(){

    $(this).leanModal({ top : 100, closeButton: ".modal_close" });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need redefine leanModal after ajax success, like:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110596/2144445