# leanModal is not working after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have problem with leanModal v 1.1,

i have php page where i implement jquery ajax pagination script , and  after this leanModal popup box not working , until i made this changes everything worked fine , i think everything cuz data now come from ajax call in one div

enyone can help me ? i have no any idea how to fix this problem !

it is leanModal jquery script

```
 $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.8, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
```

this is a link, on click this popup box i appear on site .

```
<a href="#loginmodal"   id="modaltrigger">Link</a>
```

and it is div  wich content get leanModal

```
 <div id="#loginmodal">popup box content</div>
```

it is ajax call what i use just now

```
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "myPHPfile.php",   
data:{data:data}
}).done(function(response) {
 $('#content').html(response);
    });
```

from this i get all information and insert in to div called

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i do not found any solution with leanmodal , but  perfectly work bPopup with ajax content!
here ia a link 
http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/#Options

Answer (score 0):

I think you need redefine leanModal after ajax success, like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myPHPfile.php",
    dataType:'html',
    data:{data:data},
    success:function (data, textStatus) {
        $('#content').html(data);
        $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ 
            top: 110,
            overlay: 0.8,
            closeButton: ".hidemodal"
        });
    },
});
```